# Symfony 5 - Customize Twig error templates

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony5

I'm trying to customize error templates on my Symfony 5 project. I want to use the TwigBundle error renderer because it seems to be the lightest solution.

So I followed this doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates

TwigBundle looks like correctly installed as I run this command : `composer require symfony/twig-pack` without any error.

But now I can't find any `error.html.twig` in any folder of the TwigBundle, especially in the `TwigBundle/Exception/` folder (which doesn't even exist) as suggested in the documentation.

Maybe this is not the good "TwigBundle" I installed ? Or maybe there is a better and lighter solution to customize error pages ?

Comment: Then why not add such a template file? The documentation does not state anywhere that such a file exists already

Comment: Oh sorry, my original post miss something, actually the default error template used by symfony is in the (default ?) 'error-handler' bundle in a file called 'error.html.php', and it's used for any error. So adding a file in the twig bundle won't change anything as it's not even used.

Comment: the original is actually here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/ErrorHandler/Resources/views/error.html.php but you override it according to the docs

Comment: yeah I found this one, that's the problem actually. The default template should be 'error.html.twig' in the twig-bundle folder. But symfony isn't using the twig error renderer

Comment: Please, use the answer section if you've a solution to post to help other users to find  your answer

Answer (score 6):

You need to overwrite the errors templates 
Like ->
In your templates folder you create folders like this 
templates -> bundles->TwigBundle->Exception
In the exception folder you can create one file for every type of error like 
error404.html.twig OR error403.html.twig
error.html.twig      # All other HTML errors (including 500)

```
templates/
 └─ bundles/
  └─ TwigBundle/
    └─ Exception/
      ├─ error404.html.twig
      ├─ error403.html.twig
      └─ error.html.twig      # All other HTML errors (including 500)
```

Notice that this error page will be displayed just in prod

Source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

Answer (score 1):

As [Nadim Ai Abdou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60994461/10549874),but in my environment(php8+nginx in docker) there is a extra step to clear cache

### the steps

- set `APP_ENV=prod` in `.env` file
- run `bin/console cache:clear` clear cache

I'm a beginner to symfony framework andI have no ideal why [symfony5's docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/controller/error_pages.html)
not words about the **env** and **cache**,and can't work correctly like docs

Answer (score 1):

All according to the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html AND

1. Set productive environment in .env file APP_ENV=prod
2. Сlear cache run: php bin/console cache:clear
3. **If the template error.html.twig contains errors or functions for a dev environment (such as dump()), then a standard symfony error template from vendor/symfony/error-handler will be displayed.**